# Convert text in bold to blue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I create a lot of Google Docs documents, and I have to manually format text in Bold and also in blue. To format some part of the text in bold is easy, because there's a shortcut (Ctrl+B) but it's difficult for colouring (you need 2 clicks). What if I clicked a button in a menu (created by a Google Apps Script) and it formatted all the text in bold into blue (conserving the bold).

---

An example: if we had "**Hello wo**rld" I would like to colour the "**Hello wo**" part into blue.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's true that you cannot do this with a custom menu, you can do this by creating a stand alone apps script and running that on your documents by the document ID after you make the elements bold. The following code opens a doc, gets the indicies where text formatting changes, loops through these indicies to see if it changes to bold, then colors the following section blue. This code will get you started but you need to play with it to iron out the edge cases.

```
function boldToBlue() {
  // replace with your doc ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1vfxetEhzOTXm_r9f-GanM4mSTwSkWrRsrgVsCy5laKU');
  var docText = doc.editAsText();
  var idc = docText.getTextAttributeIndices(); // gets text indicies where formatting changes

  // loop through formatting changes. If changes -> bold, make next section also blue
  for (var i = 0; i < idc.length-1; i++) {
    if (docText.isBold(idc[i])) {
      docText.setForegroundColor(idc[i], idc[i+1]-1, '#00FFFF');
    }
  }
}
```

I ran the code through your question text as a sample:

before:
[image: before image]

after:
[image: after image]

Comment: Thanks! :-) It works perfect :D I thought it would be impossible to do it... I had spent 1 hour reading the Google Apps Script documentation and I couldn't understand it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Custom menus are not currently available in Google Documents. You may file a feature request [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user).

Comment: Thank you Waqar Ahmad :-) I'll send the request.